# Trying to add numbers with in the same array

Tags: java

I have been trying to add up some numbers within the same array. I am how ever getting an java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5 error. I have tried things as

```
    for(int 1 : array)
```

After i do that i get the error java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 12

How should i try to fix this?
I am a first year student Game Development so please keep that in mind when you try to explain it to me. Thank you.

My complete code is:

```
    package com.company;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class BsaMonitor2 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int totalStudiePunt = 0;

    String[] vakNamen = {"FYS", //12 studie punten
            "Programming", "Databases", "Game Basics", "User Interaction", //3 studie punten
            "Personal Skills", "Project Skills", "Wiskunde", //2 studie punten
            "Nederlands", "English"}; //1 studie punt

    double[] cijfers = new double[10];

    int[] studiePunten = {12, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int iVak = 0; iVak < 10; iVak++) {
        while (cijfers[iVak] <= 0.9 && cijfers[iVak] >= 10.1) {
            System.out.print(vakNamen[iVak] + ": ");
            cijfers[iVak] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    for (int iVak = 0; iVak < 10; iVak++) {
        while (cijfers[iVak] <= 1 || cijfers[iVak] >= 10) {
            System.out.print(vakNamen[iVak] + ": ");
            cijfers[iVak] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }

    for (int iCijfers = 0; iCijfers < 1; iCijfers++) {
        if(cijfers[iCijfers] >= 5.5) {
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[0]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[4]);
        }
    }

    for (int iCijfers = 1; iCijfers < 5; iCijfers++) {
        if(cijfers[iCijfers] >= 5.5) {
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[1]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[4]);
        }
    }

    for (int iCijfers = 5; iCijfers < 8; iCijfers++) {
        if(cijfers[iCijfers] >= 5.5) {
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[2]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[4]);
        }
    }

    for (int iCijfers = 8; iCijfers < 10; iCijfers++) {
        if(cijfers[iCijfers] >= 5.5) {
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[3]);
        }
        else{
            System.out.printf("Vak/project: %-17s Cijfer %2.1f  Studiepunten: %d \n", vakNamen[iCijfers], cijfers[iCijfers], studiePunten[4]);
        }
    }

    for (int count = 0; count < 10; count++) {
        totalStudiePunt += studiePunten[count];
    }

    System.out.println(totalStudiePunt);

}
```

}

Comment: Neither of the code pieces you posted can produce that error. Please show the actual code as an [mcve].

Comment: man, `int 1` never compiles, `foreach` never throws an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While looping a for loop, instead of hardcording the number in middle expression, do it like this,

```
for (int count = 0; count < studiePunten.length; count++) {
    totalStudiePunt += studiePunten[count];
}
```

This way you will never get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException

Also, your code has more logical problems. This inner while loop,

```
while (cijfers[iVak] <= 0.9 && cijfers[iVak] >= 10.1)
```

it will never go through, because a number can't be less than 0.9 as well as greater than 10.1

You need to debug your program and fix the logic, which you can do best.

Comment: I have tried your code but it doesn't display the correct amount. It does show the lenght which is 18. I how ever need all the numbers added up which should sum up to 32.

Comment: I added more info in my answer. Your code has logical issues. Will suggest you to debug your program.

Comment: After a little struggling a bit i have fixed it. Thank you for your help. I'll fix the logical problem you pointed out aswell. Thank you again. How can i close this thread?

Comment: @Quintin To close the thread, click the checkmark next to an answer.